# r data.table behaviour with booleans as column selector

Tags: r, data.table

I am bit surprised by the behaviour of `data.table`. I want to select from one row in the `data.table` all non-`NA` values.

With `NA` values it's working:

```
t = data.table(a=1,b=NA)
t[, !is.na(t), with=F]
```

Without `NA` values it doesn't working:

```
t = data.table(a=1, b=2)
t[, !is.na(t), with=F]
```

The basic difference is that `t[, !c(F, F), with=F]` doesn't work. Interestingly `t[, c(T, T), with=F]` is doing fine.

I know there are many ways to achieve the desired output, but I am only interested in this - for me strange - behaviour of `data.table`.

Comment: Check out `!is.na(t)`, it's matrix. I don't know what data.table is doing with that matrix, but you want `t[, c(!is.na(t)), with=F]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've investigated the `` data.table:::`[.data.table` `` [source code](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L214)

And it indeed looks like a bug to me. What basically happens, is that the `!is.na()` call is divided into `!` and `is.na()` calls. Then, it sums this vector up, and if the length is zero it returns `null.data.table()`. The issue is, that for `dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2)`, `sum(is.na(dt))` will always be zero.

Below is a shortened code to illustrate what goes under the hood

```
sim_dt <- function(...) {

  ## data.table catches the call
  jsub <- substitute(...)
  cat("This is your call:", paste0(jsub, collapse = ""))

  ## data.table separates the `!` from the call and sets notj = TRUE instead
  ## and saves `is.na(t)` into `jsub`
  if (is.call(jsub) && deparse(jsub[[1L]], 500L, backtick=FALSE) %in% c("!", "-")) {  # TODO is deparse avoidable here?
    notj = TRUE
    jsub = jsub[[2L]]
  } else notj = FALSE

  cat("\nnotj:", notj)
  cat("\nThis is the new jsub: ", paste0(jsub, collapse = "("), ")", sep = "")

  ## data.table evaluates just the `jsub` part which obviously return a vector of `FALSE`s (because `!` was removed)
  cat("\nevaluted j:", j <- eval(jsub, setattr(as.list(seq_along(dt)), 'names', names(dt)), parent.frame()))# else j will be evaluated for the first time on next line

  ## data.table checks if `j` is a logical vector and looks if there are any TRUEs and gets an empty vector
  if (is.logical(j)) cat("\nj after `which`:", j <- which(j))

  cat("\njs length:", length(j), "\n\n")

  ## data.table checks if `j` is empty (and it's obviously is) and returns a null.data.table
  if (!length(j)) return(data.table:::null.data.table()) else return(dt[, j, with = FALSE])

}


## Your data.table
dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2)
sim_dt(!is.na(dt))
# This is your call: !is.na(dt)
# notj: TRUE
# This is the new jsub: is.na(dt)
# evaluted j: FALSE FALSE
# j after `which`: 
# js length: 0 
# 
# Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)


dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = NA)
sim_dt(!is.na(dt))

# This is your call: !is.na(dt)
# notj: TRUE
# This is the new jsub: is.na(dt)
# evaluted j: FALSE TRUE
# j after `which`: 2
# js length: 1 
# 
#     b
# 1: NA
```

Comment: The behaviour is definitely inconsistent. Thanks for looking inside and funding details.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland has already mentioned `is.na(t)` output is a matrix where you need a vector to select column.

But column selection should work in example given by `OP` as it got only single row in data.table. All we need to do is to wrap it in `()` to get that evaluated. e.g. :

```
library(data.table)
t = data.table(a=1, b=2)

t[,(!c(FALSE,FALSE)),with=FALSE]
#    a b
# 1: 1 2

t[,(!is.na(t)),with=FALSE]
#    a b
# 1: 1 2
```

Comment: I don't get the point. Why does ``t[,!c(FALSE,TRUE),with=FALSE]`` work?

Comment: @petres That's good point. But my point was to use `()` will make a force evaluation/coercing so that `!c(FALSE, FALSE)`. Perhaps you should report it as bug in GitHub.